# Visualizing the code involved in an action?

Tags: .net, debugging

I am trying to figure out how a library works and I would like to be able to visualize which methods and lines of code are executed in response to user input (e.g. a keypress or mouse click). Is there a way to do this in .NET?

Answer (score 2):

There's a wonderful, free tool from Microsoft called [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/Pex/). Once installed, you can right-click a method and select "Run Pex Exploration". It will analyze the code and show you inputs to touch every part of the method.

For more information, see [Pex CodeDigger](http://blogs.msdn.com/nikolait/archive/2008/10/21/sneak-preview-code-digger-the-new-pex-experience.aspx). Here's a screenshot of it in action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to execute the action you want to analyze from within an NUnit test, you can use the NCover utility to visualize which parts of the code were executed and which weren't.

http://www.ncover.com/

Hope this helps!

Adam

Comment: I just tried this with SharpDevelop + PartCover, but my form won't initialize during a unit test due to a mysterious exception - "DragDrop registration did not succeed"

Anyway it's not a good solution as I want to see the code that runs in response to a specific action, not ALL the code that runs.

Comment: It can definitely be tough to unit test UI code.  Assuming you have a very thin UI layer where a button click event does nothing but call a single method on a controller class, you could unit test the controller method instead of the click event.  That may get you closer to what you need, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a code coverage tool like [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) even without any unit testing frameworks. Just run the application through NCover, and check the results.

Edit: you might also want to check out [PartCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/), an open source alternative.

Comment: Can code coverage detection be restricted to only part of the application run (excluding startup/shutdown)?

Comment: Depends on the tool. With NCover you can restrict amongst others to only cover specific assemblies using command line switches (see http://www.ncover.com/documentation/console/flags for details).