# Looking to visualize debugging: variables and instances created by classes and functions graphically drawn

Tags: debugging, visualization

First of all, I do not believe this belongs on Superuser. This belongs here because it is strictly programming related.

What I am looking for is a program that will visualize(draw it on the screen or something) how programs create variables, make pointers from the stack to the heap, variable names and contents, and so on.

Kinda like a diagram/flowchart thing, but automatically drawn for you.

Does such a thing exist?

EDIT: i just came across this topic: [Visualizing the code involved in an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268906/visualizing-the-code-involved-in-an-action), that's not what I'm looking for, I'm talking about some really graphic and dynamic.

EDIT:

I found 1 thing, but it's not really great and kinda old.

jElliot, demo can be viewed here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5ahEgu5Ba0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on one of the UNIX platforms, you might want to look at DDD.

Comment: Exactly like that. Now we just need something that also works on Windoze and is more suitable for displaying much bigger object graphs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen [Ben Fry's work](http://benfry.com/disarticulate/) in this space?

Comment: No, I took a look am I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for. I added an example to the original post, which may make things more clear.